# How to set UITableView cells width to same as its parent/device width?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]

I have a `UITableView` cells that won't follow it's parent width. I found so many codes for how to change the height, however I couldn't found codes/ways to change `UITableView` cells to same as it parents.

Some of answer told that it would follow automatically. But in mine, the problem is the width can't follow device's width. Is there anyone that know how to change it?

Comment: what do u mean by parent ?

Comment: Please share your code by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53496893/edit)-ing the question.

Comment: Don't forget to share what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @vivekDas UIStoryboard / my device width

Comment: @RakeshaShastri I already edit it :)

Comment: @RatulSharker done

Comment: for width you don't have to do anything bro !! according to the tableview width cell width set automatically !

Comment: @vivekDas is right, just shrink the `UITableView` width wise, according to your requirement.

Comment: What about the constraints in the cell?
If you have set your UI Correctly then the cell will take the entire width of the tableview. This is how it is designed to work.

Comment: It doesn't work if I change the device screen. It doesn't follow the device screen's width.

Comment: @AlanSarraf I think I already set my UI Correctly. When I change the width, the item in the cell just adjust it. The problem is when I test in different screen size, it won't follow the screen size.

Comment: Do you mean changing device orientation (Portrait to landscape) or it works on a smaller device but on a larger device it doesn't take the full width?

Comment: @AlanSarraf, no, I mean the device, example from iPhone XR to iPhone 6

Comment: Then make sure that your table view is constrained correctly. If you want it to take the full width, instead of giving the tableview a fixed width constraint, give it leading and trailing constraints with value 0

Comment: @AlanSarraf I couldn't add leading and trailing to it. When I ctrl and drag it, it only shows the option to change the height or width and aspect ratio.

Comment: You don't add leading and trailing with ctrl drag. You have to use the Pin tool. Follow this link and check the Pin Tool section: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `UITableviewCell` width will always be the same width of the `UITableView`.

If you want to set the width of the cell same as the parent of `UITableView`, You should set the width of the `UITableView` same as that of parent

If you want to set the width of `UITableView` the same as it's parent view, set the trailing and leading constraints of your `UITableView` to it's superview with value 0

you need to remove the width constraint and aspect ratio that you have added to it. Instead of ctrl and drag, select the tableview and click the pin button and set the constraints as shown in [image: this] image. Remember the trailing and leading values must be 0 for setting the width as same as parent view

Comment: How to change the width of UITableView then? Because in mine I couldn't change it.

Comment: Please show the design that you used in storyboard. Did you used constraints to set the width?

Comment: For which view did you added the width constraint?

Comment: I already add it. I want to add to the first view after the safe area.

Comment: Is your tableview's parent view the first view after safe area? What is the leading and trailing constraint value of table view?

Comment: Yes it is. It was the first view after safe area.

Comment: What is the leading and trailing constraint value of table view?

Comment: I couldn't add leading and trailing to it. When I ctrl and drag it, it only shows the option to change the height or width and aspect ratio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184315/discussion-between-bali-and-firda-sahidi).

Comment: You shouldn't add a constant width constraint to the tableView if you want the width of its parent. Instead use trailing and leading constraints, set its value to 0

Comment: Just pin the UITableView left and right constraints to the superview with value 0.